# Rule 30 Cellular Automata 3 colors in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, cellular-automata

May I ask you if I can use the CA rule 30 with 3 colors in Mathematica?

Regards,

Daniele

Comment: This seems like a [**duplicate question of the following one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807744).

Comment: possible duplicate of [CA Random 3 colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807744/ca-random-3-colors)